# Override parent max width that has position relative

Tags: css

I have a full-container that has a max-width of 1080px and has position relative, all content falls in that div. I have a div(.portfolio) and i want that div(.portfolio) to have a max-widh of 100% so its filled over the whole width of the page.
I can't change the max width of the full-container because i want the rest off the content to have a max-width off 1080px.

So my question is, is there a way to override the parents max width in what way doesn't matter.

i tried to use position absolute on the div(.portfolio) but that doesn't work ofcourse...

Comment: Close the container, have your full width div, open a new container. Simple really.

Comment: as i said all content falls in it, its a wordpress page so i dont think i can do that.

Comment: Then it's a matter of adjusting your theme I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah thats what i think... but i thought ill give it a try :)

Comment: is there a way to get the div out of the full-container with jquery maybe? or close the div and open it somewhere else

Comment: @Paulie_D you think this is a good solution?: i removed the div full-container out of tyhe theme and added a css class : .wrap than i added some jquery that adds the class .wrap(max-width: 1080px) to all the parent divs in the content and than i manually remove the div .wrap in jquery on parts that don't need a max-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define new width you want to override to `.full-container` which contains `.portfolio` adding a class:

```
.full-container.pp{
  max-width: 1200px;/*override value with your wish*/
}


<div class="full-container pp"><!--max-width: 1200px-->
  <div class="portfolio"></div>
</div>
<div class="full-container"><!--max-width: 1080px-->
</div>
```

Now your portfolio would contain `100%` width `max-width: 1200px`

Comment: OP must do like this, else there is no way to go portfolio div outside the full-container

Comment: I've updated my answer as community wiki so the OP can rely on this or no-option there...

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me. i guess ill change the theme so i can do this i thought there might be another way but there isn't so i don't have to change my theme.